# Python turtle game, making walls that aren't outside borders, fixing NoneType error code, not iterable

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, nonetype

Everything was working fine until I put in everything involving win and finish, then it keeps telling me that a code that was working before, is now not iterable. What is supposed to happen is when they cross a certain distance they get somewhere else on the map, I don't care wear else, this is just a test. I keep getting the error code.

```
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in 
__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
fun()
File "E:\Home made game\original.py", line 183, in k1
elif win(player):
File "E:\Home made game\original.py", line 37, in win
return inside(position, winner)
File "E:\Home made game\original.py", line 7, in inside
x1 = min(p[0] for p in rectangle)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'
```

And here is the rest of my code.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def inside(point, rectangle):
    x, y = point

    # not efficient, just a quick solution
    x1 = min(p[0] for p in rectangle)
    y1 = min(p[1] for p in rectangle)
    x2 = max(p[0] for p in rectangle)
    y2 = max(p[1] for p in rectangle)

    return x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2

def not_safe(turtle):
    position = turtle.position()
    return inside(position, river) and not inside(position, bridge)

def winLine(turtle):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.color('red')
    turtle.goto(-WIDTH / 2, 0)

    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

def win(turtle):
    position = turtle.position()
    return inside(position, winner)

def drawTree(t, sd):
    for i in range(4):
        layout.down()
        t.forward(sd)
        t.right(90)
        layout.up()

def drawRiver(turtle):
    turtle.color('darkblue', 'blue')

    turtle.goto(-WIDTH / 2, 0)

    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

def tree(branchLen,layout):
    if branchLen > 6:
        layout.down()
        layout.forward(branchLen)
        layout.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-6,layout)
        layout.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-6,layout)
        layout.right(20)
        layout.backward(branchLen)
        layout.up()

def main():
    layout.speed('fastest')
    layout.left(90)
    layout.up()
    layout.backward(100)
    layout.down()
    layout.color("brown")
    tree(36,layout)
    layout.right(90)
    layout.up()


def drawBridge(turtle):
    turtle.goto(150, 25)
    turtle.color('rosybrown4', 'saddlebrown')

    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

def drawPlanks(turtle):
    layout.goto(149, -125)
    for i in range(37):
        layout.pensize(.1)
        layout.down()
        layout.color("black")
        layout.forward(.3)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(99)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(.3)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(99)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.up()
        layout.forward(4)
    layout.goto(149, 25)
    layout.down()
    layout.left(90)
    layout.forward(100)
    layout.pensize(.1)
    layout.up()
    layout.goto(149, -125)
    layout.down()
    layout.right(90)
    layout.forward(151)
    layout.up()
    layout.goto(49, -125)
    layout.down()
    layout.forward(151)
 wn = Screen()
 wn.bgcolor('lightgreen')
 WIDTH = wn.window_width()

layout = Turtle(visible=False)
layout.speed('fastest')
layout.penup()

river = drawRiver(layout)
bridge = drawBridge(layout)
planks = drawPlanks(layout)
winner= winLine(layout)
layout.up()
layout.right(90)

# Tree locations
layout.goto(222, 198)
main()
layout.goto(-334, 155)
main()
layout.goto(132, 140)
main()
layout.goto(50, -222)
main()
layout.goto(200, -122)
main()
layout.goto(-362,200)
main()
layout.goto(-222, 198)
main()
layout.goto(350, 350)
main()
layout.goto(-200, -150)
main()
layout.color("blue")
layout.goto(0, -50)
player = Turtle('arrow')
player.color('grey')
player.penup()

player.goto(0, -200)
player.setheading(90)


def k1():
    player.forward(45)
    if not_safe(player):
        player.goto(0, -200)
        player.setheading(90)
    elif win(player):
        player.goto(200, 100)

def k4():
    player.back(45)
    if not_safe(player):
        player.goto(0, -200)
        player.setheading(90)
    elif win(player):
        player.goto(200, 100)

def k2():
    player.left(30)

def k3():
    player.right(30)

wn.onkey(k1, "Up")
wn.onkey(k2, "Left")
wn.onkey(k3, "Right")
wn.onkey(k4, "Down")

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is `rectangle` in last line of error ? Probably you have one element in `rectangle` but you use it as list in `min(p[0] for p in rectangle)`. You can use `print(rectangle)` or `print( type(rectangle) )` to check it.

Comment: you have variable `finish = ...` and function `def finish(...)` - it makes problem when you use `inside(..., finish)` because it puts function `finish` not variable `finish`. Bu tmaybe you should use something different instead of `finish` in `inside(..., finish)`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a polygon to these variables:

```
river = drawRiver(layout)
bridge = drawBridge(layout)
planks = drawPlanks(layout)
winner = winLine(layout)
```

However, the two functions drawPlanks and winLine do not return a polygon; they return `None` by default, which is assigned to `planks` and `winner`; later, when you call `inside` on `winner`, it passes `None` instead of a `polygon` as argument. You need to add `return turtle.get_poly()` for both these functions:

```
def winLine(turtle):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.color('red')
    turtle.goto(-WIDTH / 2, 0)

    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()      # <-- here
```

and:

```
def drawPlanks(turtle):
    layout.goto(149, -125)
    for i in range(37):
        layout.pensize(.1)
        layout.down()
        layout.color("black")
        layout.forward(.3)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(99)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(.3)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.forward(99)
        layout.left(90)
        layout.up()
        layout.forward(4)
    layout.goto(149, 25)
    layout.down()
    layout.left(90)
    layout.forward(100)
    layout.pensize(.1)
    layout.up()
    layout.goto(149, -125)
    layout.down()
    layout.right(90)
    layout.forward(151)
    layout.up()
    layout.goto(49, -125)
    layout.down()
    layout.forward(151)

    return turtle.get_poly()      # <-- and there
```